# Two ways to define a model class in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Forgive my ignorance, I want to know what is the difference between:

```
class Car extends Backbone.Model {

}
```

and

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

As silly as I was, the first expression is from coffee script syntax, which compiles to the lower one (not exactly, but does the same thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the first one is NOT javascript.
2. javascript extend is different from java extend

> JavaScript's dynamism allows us to add or replace methods of an
>   existing class. We can call the method method at any time, and all
>   present and future instances of the class will have that method. We
>   can literally extend a class at any time. Inheritance works
>   retroactively. We call this Class Augmentation to avoid confusion with
>   Java's extends, which means something else.

from http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html